# How to get features of CompletionListener class in JMS using ActiveMQ "Classic"?

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm using ActiveMQ "Classic" for my JMS application which is a simple chat application in which I would like to get notified when a message is sent successfully. If failed then the reason for failure. These features are implemented in `javax.jms.CompletionListener`, but the activemq-all-xxx.jar does not contain this class. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`javax.jms.CompletionListener` is part of JMS 2.0 which ActiveMQ 5.x doesn't implement. If you really want this functionality then you should migrate to [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) (ActiveMQ's next-generation broker) which *does* implement JMS 2.0.

To be clear `javax.jms.CompletionListener` is used to get notified about messages which are sent *asynchronously*. If sending message asynchronously isn't a requirement for your application you could simply send them synchronously and you would get notified of failures, etc. directly from the sending method call.

Comment: what will be the replacement for "<amq:topic id="mqTopic" physicalName="JMStopic" /> ". if possible please share the sample configuration file.

Comment: and also what will be the replacement for <amq:connectionFactory id="mqConnectionFactory" brokerURL="tcp://PC" />

Comment: You're going to have to provide some context for that XML as I don't know where it came from? Please clarify, ideally in a new question.